# Install VS DOC file for jQuery in Visual Studio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, nuget, vsdoc

Using package console in Visual Studio, we install jQuery using

install-package jquery

Is there command to install VS doc file for the corresponding jQuery file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc